# LINQ-to-SQL using tables dynamically by name

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

Is this possible ? or any workaround is possible

```
string table="language";
var a=_db.table.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This really has nothing to do specifically to ASP.NET or MVC

Answer (score 2):

First find the Type being represented by the name, then call `_db.GetTable<T>()` like this:

```
string entityName = "language";

var entityType = FindType(entityName);

var result = _db.GetTable<entityType>().FirstOrDefault;
```

The helper method `FindType()` gets the Type through Reflection:

```
public Type FindType(string typeName) {
    foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
        var result = assembly.GetType(typeName, false, true);
        if (result != null) { return result; }
    }
    throw new Exception("Selected type can't be found in loaded assemblies");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the entity type (rather than just a string) you can use `_db.GetTable()`